# php eclipse phpunit make good : Unable to run test

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit, xdebug

I am trying to configure phpunit and makegood in eclipse. I am able to use phpunit via command line but I am not able to run my test with in eclipse.
I am very new to php world. I have installed php using brew. In eclipse preference, which dir I should set in 'PHP Libraries' this library is named PEAR in most of blogs.

When I open 'MakeGood' view in eclipse, it says 'Waiting for a test run' and when I do 'Run All Tests', following is printed on console

```
Warning: Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Stagehand_TestRunner version 3.6.1

Copyright (c) 2005-2013 KUBO Atsuhiro and contributors,
All rights reserved.

Usage:
  [options] command [arguments]

Options:
  --help           -h Prints help and exit.
  --version        -V Prints version information and exit.
  --ansi              Enables ANSI output.
  --no-ansi           Disables ANSI output.

Testing Framework Commands:
 cakephp               Runs tests with CakePHP.
 ciunit                Runs tests with CIUnit.
 phpspec               Runs tests with PHPSpec.
 phpunit               Runs tests with PHPUnit.
 simpletest            Runs tests with SimpleTest.

Other Commands:
  compile               Compiles the DIC for the production environment.
  help                  Prints the help for a command.
  list                  Lists commands.
  phpunit:passthrough   Runs the phpunit command via the testrunner command.
```

Following is my phpunit xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    backupGlobals               = "false"
    backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
    colors                      = "true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
    processIsolation            = "false"
    stopOnFailure               = "false"
    syntaxCheck                 = "false"
    bootstrap                   = "bootstrap.php" >
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Lamed Test Suite">
        <directory>test</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Please guide
Thanks